# SwiftUI Picker return empty string from CoreData

Tags: core-data, swiftui, picker

How to improve this? Picker returns empty String when I use `ForEach` (CoreData entities). If I use `testing[String]` everything works fine

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddTask: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Goal.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var goals: FetchedResults<Goal>
    
    @State private var taskName: String = ""
    @State private var originGoal = ""
    private let testGoal = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section{
                    TextField("Enter Task Name", text: $taskName)
                }
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $originGoal, label: Text("Choose Goal")) {
                        ForEach(goals, id: \.self) { goal in
                            Text(goal.wrappedName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        Button("Add") {
            let task1 = Task(context: self.moc)
            task1.name = taskName
            task1.origin = Goal(context: self.moc)
            task1.origin?.name = originGoal
            
            try? self.moc.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe there are nice alternatives for SwiftUI Picker?

Comment: What do you mean by `Picker return empty String`?

Comment: Picker don't choose any variant from Goals List, show, but don't select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selection` and `id` should be the same type in `Picker`, so try (cannot test your code):

```
Section {
    Picker(selection: $originGoal, label: Text("Choose Goal")) {
        ForEach(goals, id: \.wrappedName) { goal in
            Text(goal.wrappedName)
        }
    }
}
```

sometimes also `tag` works (but was reported not always), so try as well

```
Section {
    Picker(selection: $originGoal, label: Text("Choose Goal")) {
        ForEach(goals, id: \.self) { goal in
            Text(goal.wrappedName).tag(goal.wrappedName)
        }
    }
}
```